# Error invoking generator in transpiled output

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have a JavaScript module defined as follows:

```
const getQueryParameters = function* (obj, prefix) {
  for (const [k1, v1] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    const name = prefix === undefined || prefix === null ? k1 : `${prefix}.${k1}`;

    if (typeof v1 === 'object') {
      for (const [k2, v2] of getQueryParameters(v1, name)) {
        yield [k2, v2];
      }
    }
    else {
      yield [name, v1];
    }
  }
};

module.exports = getQueryParameters;
```

In a vue SFC, I am importing it as follows:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
const getQueryParameters = require('../../modules/get-query-parameters.js');
```

I am attempting to call it as follows:

```
const myObject = {
  'foo': 42,
  'bar': {
    'baz': 'bof'
  }
};
const params = {};
for (const [k, v] of getQueryParameters(myObject, null)) {
    params[k] = v;
}
```

Finally, I then transpile it with webpack and babel using a `.babelrc` as follows:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "last 2 versions",
            "IE >= 11"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The procedure runs fine from node (w/o transpiling it) as expected, however when attempting to run it in a browser, I get the following error:

```
vue.esm.js?a026:1741 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
    at getQueryParameters$ (get-query-parameters.js?5f2b:64)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?f3a2:65)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?f3a2:303)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
    at getQueryParameters$ (get-query-parameters.js?5f2b:63)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?f3a2:65)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?f3a2:303)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
    at getQueryParameters$ (get-query-parameters.js?5f2b:63)
```

I imagine my babel configuration is incomplete but looking at the error, the correct babel plugins (`regenerator-runtime`) are invoked as I originally expected. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: seems like your `myObject` is `undefined`or `null`

Comment: Sorry, I left it out thinking it would not add value, however it is valid and I have updated the question.

Comment: Works for me. What does `getQueryParameters` from `const getQueryParameters = require('../../modules/get-query-parameters.js');` return ?

Comment: The function, are you transpiling it with Babel and then bindling it through webpack?

Comment: It's very likely you have this problem https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2030 which is caused by `module.exports` getting ignored by webpack if you miss declaring `target` check here https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/

Comment: I usually switch off module transpilation in babel and let webpack handle it, you can do it in `.babelrc` with `{ modules: false }` in `env`

Comment: Ok, that added significant clarity, thank you. The import from the webpack/babel processed code in a browser does yield an undefined object. However none of the suggestions in the linked issue resolve it for me.

Comment: can you upload your minimal configuration so I can run with the whole setup and try to reproduce?

Comment: I would be grateful! Let me put together a repro without database access etc.

Comment: I have created a repro using the exact `webpack.config.js` and `.babelrc` however the repro uses `webpack-dev-server` which is working:( My project is an asp.net core app which fails with both `aspnet-webpack` and `webpack-hot-middleware` or manually compiled output from a webpack build?